Beatles reference in parody story from the 1980s
This was a story almost certainly from Asimovs. All I remember is one line about the alien invaders: something like "Their names was Legion, they called themselves Skreegion, but among their victims everyone knew them as the Nansi" (a reference to the song "Rocky Raccoon" and its lonely "Her name was McGill, she called herself Lil, but everyone knew her as Nancy").

This is Dèjá Lu by Henry Clark.

The Kanamit, the Kzinti, the Tralfamadorians, the Groaci—cacogens all,
their name was legion, they called themselves Skreejon, but everyone
knew them as Nansi—deterred armed resistance by incising holes in the
earth where defense plants had been. Military bases became skating
rinks, their smooth glassy surfaces—without a hint of radiation,
despite what lay buried beneath—proving suitable for nothing else. The
Nansi conquered the earth in less time than it had taken Wells’s
Martians, and, going the Martians one better, had done it outside a
fictional context.

It was published in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine 1984 Vol. 8 #11. You can read it online here if you have an Archive.org login

Could be and was. I bet I read it before I would have recognized the name Groaci, too.

I wonder if I can find that issue in my piles of old Asimovs
